# Connect a device from Sigfox or LoraWan to Kaa with Java SDK

Tags: java, sdk, kaa, lorawan

I am in charge of developing an application as PoC with the basic functions of  *Kaa*.  I am new in the field of *IoT*.

So for the application: First I generate the *Java SDK* then I insert it into my application as lib.

So my questions are :

1) The role of the SDK is to connect a device from *Sigfox* or *LoraWan* to *Kaa*, or my application will consume the Web Services of *Sigfox* and *LoRa* then use the *SDK* to process the data with *Kaa* and save it in *mongoDB*?

2) And, how to get the connection between the client and the server?

3) And if I want to use a module like *Data Collection Demo*, I have to generate the *SDK* of this module ?

Sorry for all these questions but I have to understand the basics to move forward in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The Kaa SDK implements all the necessary functionality to connect and communicate with the Kaa server including all its features. This eliminates necessity to develop any network protocols for talking to server. You should simply use the Kaa SDK API and it will handle all the processing under the hood. This is the role of the Kaa SDK.

Thus:

1) You should add all the necessary integration with services you need aside Kaa to the application. Then, the application should use Kaa SDK to upload the data to Kaa server, etc.

2) There is no direct access to the Kaa client-to-server connection available from the Kaa SDK. As there is much of the protocol handling done through the connection, it is available only through the Kaa SDK API. You should normally have no reason to get in depth of the Kaa protocol and connection to server.

3) The Kaa SDK includes all the necessary modules provided you made the necessary configuration on server side before generating of the SDK. This means that you should re-generate the SDK if there are changes to the configuration on the server side for this application.

We recommend starting with [Your first Kaa application](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/). That shows how to create a simple Kaa-based application with Data Collection feature. More sample applications you can find on [GitHub](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps).